# configuring syslog-ng server on ec2 instances

Tags: amazon-ec2, cloud, legacy, syslog-ng

I am trying  to install a syslog-ng server on ec2 instance .As part  of legacy configuration I require my hosts to be  grouped based on their hostnames.Since ec2 instances are not keeping a common hostname like the legacy ,I am confused how to achieve the syslog   server setup .Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not into EC2, so it might be totally unrelated, but @peter-czanik had a blogpost about [installing syslog-ng on AWS Linux AMI](https://syslog-ng.com/blog/installing-syslog-ng-aws-linux-ami/)